# Good jquery character count script?

Tags: jquery

does any know a good jquery character count script, tutorial or plugin?

Comment: Does it need to distinguish between valid and invalid combining forms?

Comment: huh? I just want to count the characters and stop at a certain number in a textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several [in the plugins repository](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/character-counter) :)

If you're looking for a *specific* plugin, be sure to check out [jQuery Simply Countable](https://github.com/aaronrussell/jquery-simply-countable/), you can check out [a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ja6fH/), it's pretty lightweight and does the essentials well with optional event handlers for any custom functionality you want to tie in.

Comment: I think people coming to this page are looking for a particular recommendation, rather than a link to the plugin repository, which most people are already aware of.

Comment: Good thing his link isn't general. Maybe you should think twice before correcting someone with 162k rep.

Comment: @Homer6 I knew that already. Most people on this site also know how to use a search box.  The question asks for *good* plugins, and his link contains several which IMO don't qualify.

Comment: @Muhd - did you even *look* at the link, or just judge it before visiting? Any recommendation here is likely to be outdated fast, where as a link to the repository with more current info survives the test of time, and is of more use to future visitors.